# Trabajo con lista en C# por consola

Tags: c#

Estoy aprendiendo [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) hace pocos días, me toca resolver un ejercicio que no puedo entender. Necesito si me pueden aclarar como realizarlo.

La consigna es crear una clase `Estudiantes` con 2 variables privadas (atributos), `string nombre` y `List<double> notas`.

La idea es hardcodear 3 estudiantes, agregar 3 o 4 notas a cada uno, y luego crear los métodos para agregar y promedio de notas.

Principalmente necesito poder crear la clase, me complica la existencia del `List`… Copio lo que tengo, que no funciona. gracias adelantadas.

Con ayuda me ha funcionado el siguiente código, pero a medias , no se como agregar items a la lista ni como implementar un `foreach` para ver estudiante + nota.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

internal class Program
{ 
    class Estudiante
    {
        private string nombre = string.Empty;
        private List<double> notas = new List<double>();

        public Estudiante(string nombre_estudiante, List<double> notas_estudiante)
        {
            nombre = nombre_estudiante;
            notas = notas_estudiante;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new Estudiante("Pepe Monje", new List<double> { 10, 7, 3 });
        var b = new Estudiante("Alicia Perez", new List<double> { 5, 5, 10 });
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes dos maneras de conseguir tu objetivo, la primera sería redactando una función que permita establecer el valor después de que el objeto `Estudiante` se haya construido, la segunda sería modificando el constructor para que reciba una colección de `double`s (en lugar de sólo uno).

##### [*Setters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) y Propiedades.

En [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tienes dos maneras de dar acceso controlado a valores internos de tus clases, la tradicional de la mayoría de lenguajes de programación orientados a objetos es con un *setter*:

```
class Estudiante
{
    // En singular, cada estudiante sólo tiene un nombre
    private string nombre = string.Empty;
    private List<double> notas = new List<double>();
   
    // En esta versión, no añadimos constructor

    // Función para asignar valor al nombre del estudiante
    public void SetNombre(string nombre_estudiante)
    {
        nombre = nombre_estudiante;
    }
    // Función para añadir una nota al estudiante
    public void AnadirNota(double nota)
    {
        notas.Add(nota);
    }
}
```

Puede usarse así:

```
a.SetNombre("Pepe Monje");
a.AnadirNota(10);
a.AnadirNota(7);
a.AnadirNota(3);

b.SetNombre("Alicia Perez");
b.AnadirNota(5);
b.AnadirNota(5);
b.AnadirNota(10);
```

La manera al estilo C# es generando propiedades:

```
class Estudiante
{
    // En singular, cada estudiante sólo tiene un nombre
    private string nombre = string.Empty;
    private List<double> notas = new List<double>();
   
    // En esta versión, no añadimos constructor

    // Propiedad que da acceso al nombre.
    public string Nombre
    {
        get { return nombre; }
        set { nombre = value; }
    }
    // Propiedad que da acceso a las notas.
    // No le añadimos 'set' para que no se pueda sobrescribir la lista.
    public List<double> Notas
    {
        get { return notas; }
    }
}
```

Puede usarse así:

```
a.Nombre = "Pepe Monje";
a.Nota.Add(10);
a.Nota.Add(7);
a.Nota.Add(3);

b.Nombre = "Alicia Perez";
b.Nota.Add(5);
b.Nota.Add(5);
b.Nota.Add(10);
```

##### Constructor.

Puedes asignar directamente las notas en el constructor de la clase `Estudiante`:

```
public Estudiante(string nombre_estudiante, List<double> notas_estudiante)
{
    nombre = nombre_estudiante;
    notas = notas_estudiante;
}
```

Puede usarse así:

```
var a = new Estudiante("Pepe Monje", new List<double>{10, 7, 3});
var b = new Estudiante("Alicia Perez", new List<double>{5, 5, 10});
```

Comment: Si nos sentimos atrevidos, podemos hacer `Promedio` una propiedad también: `public decimal Promedio => Notas.Count == 0 ? 0m : Notas.Aggregate(0m,(accumulador, nota) => accumulador + nota)/ Notas.Count;`

Comment: Hola , estoy estudiando esto .. porque no me funciona. La consigna es usar constructor , se me mezcla un poco lo que me has pasado.

Comment: Edite el codigo original. Me sale 1 error : Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error CS1520 El método debe tener un tipo de valor devuelto Estudiantes C:\ACTUAL\Estudiantes\Program.cs 1

Comment: @look68 en las respuestas y en los comentarios tienes el código necesario tanto para añadir notas a los alumnos como para calcular el promedio de las notas.

Answer (score 1):

Debes cambiar tu constructor para recibir la lista de notas.

```
public Estudiante(string _nombres, List<double> _notas)
{
    nombres = _nombres;
    notas = _notas;
}
```

Al momento de crear un objeto le pasas la lista de notas, en ese caso puedes crear solicitar al usuario la cantidad de estudiantes y por cada estudiante consultar la cantidad de notas que va a ingresar y hacer la creación del objeto usando bucles.

Creo que este video puede ser de utilidad.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkJX6aFh0ww

Comment: Gracias, ya vi ese link, pero tengo que hacerlo con constructor y utilizando List<Estudiante>estudiantes = new List<Estudiante>()  en el main

Comment: Ahi me funcionó a medias .. si me ayudas .. creo que sale

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que debes saber cual es el nombre correcto de cada "elemento"

```
public class UnaClase{
  private int a; // Esto es un campo (Field)

  private int b { get; set; } // Esto es una propiedad (Property)

  [Range(0, int.MaxValue)] // <- Esto es un atributo (Attribute)
  private int c { get; set; }
}
```

---

Tener 2 campos privados (nombre y notas) implica que deberás crear funciones asociadas para ingresar datos y otra para obtener sus datos, a estas funciones se las concen como (getters/setters). Esta forma de codificación es común en otros lenguajes con JAVA, en C# no lo hacemos de esa manera porque nuestro tiempo es valioso, nosotros usamos las **Propiedades**

Te dejo un código completo

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Estudiante> estudiantes = new List<Estudiante>
        {
             new Estudiante("Estudiante 1", new() { 1, 2, 3, 4 }),
             new Estudiante("Estudiante 2", new() { 4, 4 }),
             new Estudiante("Estudiante 3", new() { 2, 7, 8 }),
        };

        //otra forma de crear estudiante
        Estudiante estudiante4 = new("Estudiante 4");
        estudiante4.notas.Add(2); //agregamos una nota
        estudiante4.notas.Add(3); //agregamos otra nota
        estudiante4.notas.AddRange(new List<double>{ 6,7,8 }); //agregamos una lista de notas

        foreach(var estudiante in estudiantes) { 
            Console.WriteLine($"{estudiante.Nombre} sus notas son: {string.Join(", ",estudiante.notas)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Y su promedio es: {estudiante.notas.Average()}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
public class Estudiante
{
    public string Nombre { get; set;} = string.Empty; // get y set son publicos
    public List<double> notas { get; private set; } = new(); //get es publico pero set es privado


    //Creamos 2 constructores uno que incluye una lista de notas y otro sin esta lista
    public Estudiante(string nombre) => Nombre = nombre;
    public Estudiante(string nombre, List<double> notas)
    {
        Nombre = nombre;
        this.notas = notas; //usamos this porque tenemos el argumento "nota" y la propiedad nota que tienen el mismo nombre
    }
}
```

Si te fijas bien en el código anterior te darás cuenta que en la propiedad de notas he puesto el `get` como público, lo cual te permite tener acceso directo a la lista, la ventaja de esto es que la lista ya cuenta con funciones que tu necesitas utilizar como `Add` para agregar y `Average` para calcular el promedio.

Comment: Hola, gracias , estoy tratando de entender, uso visual studio 2019 y me da error al cargar las notas ... dice : Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error CS8370 La característica "creación de objetos con tipo de destino" no está disponible en C# 7.3. Use la versión 9.0 del lenguaje o una posterior. Estudiantes01 C:\ACTUAL\Estudiantes01\Program.cs 15

Comment: Actualmente se usa .net 7 que tiene C# 10. tu estas usando una versión muy vieja del lenguaje. Aun que para mi ejemplo creo que solo hay que cambiar esta línea `public Estudiante(string nombre) => Nombre = nombre;` por esta public Estudiante(string nombre) { Nombre = nombre; }

Answer (score -1):

Las respuestas me han ayudado a entender un poco mas.Tuve que cambiar el desarrollo a algo que entiendo mejor. Igual, se agradece!